# Why does $dy/dt=5y^{4/5}$ not satisfy the Uniqueness theorem?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm just wondering if my answer is correct. Why does $$\frac{dy}{dt}=5y^{4/5}$$ not satisfy the Uniqueness theorem? My thinking is since every number and its corresponding negative result in the same answer, then $\frac{dy}{dt}$ does not satisfy the Uniqueness Theorem in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: its supposed to be to the power of 4/5

Comment: I fixed the exponents for you

Comment: thanks for that..im on my phone and it wouldnt let me edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to set $F(t, y) = 5y^{4/5}$, so our ODE is $\frac{dy}{dt} = F(t, y)$. The existence and uniqueness theorem only applies if $F(t, y)$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(t, y)$ are both continuous. However, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(t, y) = 4 y^{-1/5}$, which is not defined, let alone continuous, at $y=0$.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the existence and uniqueness theorem only applies if $F(t, y)$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(t, y)$ are both continuous. You can have existence and uniqueness under weaker conditions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The existence and uniqueness theorem typically given in undergraduate ODE courses assumes that $F$ and $\partial F/\partial y$ are both continuous. This is the only theorem to which OP is likely allowed to appeal. Of course, a theorem can only be used if its hypotheses are met.

Comment: @AlexG. Personnally, I never met your version of the theorem, it was always Cauchy-Lipschitz that we used, even in undergraduate courses

Comment: @Tryss I guess it depends on the undergrad program. I took ODEs in my first year, a full year before I learned the definition of Lipschitz continuity.